# Extract string from string in Bash

Tags: bash

The script reads in lines from a text file. A line looks like this.

```
227 A S  comment=comment string dst-address=9.9.9.9/29 gateway=192.168.199.2 gateway-status=192.168.199.2 reachable via  LACP1=1 scope=30 target-scope=10
```

This is assigned the variable $route

I then need to then assign `9.9.9.9/29` as the variable `$subnet`. I can't use `awk` because the column position of dst-address will vary in the lines.

To recap I need to search each line for "`dst-address=`" and then assign the string after the '=' to the variable $subnet.

My ideal solution is

```
while read routes ; do
    subnet=< code I need >
done < /tmp/routingTable.txt
```

Comment: `grep -oP 'dst-address=\K[^ ]*'`?

Comment: Very useful command, I'll have other uses for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bash solution without a loop

```
echo $route | sed -r "s/.*dst-address=([0-9./]+).*/\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Perl` solution:

```
perl -n -e'/dst-address=(\S+)/ && print $1."\n"' your_file
```